# What is the danger of using ground as the return path in normal use?

Tags: ground, grounding

I watched [a video in which a man showing how to save money by only spanning a single cable as follows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UgQwOkk_2Q).

[image]

The ac current passes through the single 30 meter long cable, a breaker, a lamp, and return via the ground.

What is the danger of this mechanism?

Comment: Can't tell you about the assumptions a video makes that I've not seen. Generally, if a video makes unexplained claims, it might not be the greatest video (**very** few youtube videos are *good*, most are really inacceptably *bad*, to be honest, just in case you plan on learning from youtube. The youtube algorithm rewards videos with wrong simplifications that seem especially easy, and flashy results that just don't work in reality.)

Comment: All of the load current at the chicken farm has to go through the earth. That will likely develop a significant ground-voltage difference given any significant load current at the farm. It might work well enough for really low current loads (such as shocking the human body, for example.) It may also work better if there is a water pipe buried in the ground going from the house to the farm. But then it might be better to clamp that pipe. With load, it's also dangerous as it raises the local ground at the chicken house. And I'd worry about increased galvanic corrosion and metal migration, too.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I edited my question with the video.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Don't trust something you hear in a YouTube video unless you already know that everything else that was said in the YoutTube video is good.

Comment: It's not unheard of.  Given the cost of 30m of wire it's a needless risk and may not be up to code depending where you live.  That said, single wire transmission lines are still used in Canada for power distribution in remote areas.  To know exactly how acceptable the risk was, you'd have to examine the content and quality of the earth in your area.  Up in the rocky north it can be hard to get an adequate ground rod connection and would be worse over long distances.

Comment: The further you go back in electrical history, the more examples you see of crazy and sometimes ingenious ways to save wire, but these days a lot of those practices are frowned on because they can make maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: This actually won't work to the extent that I would call it a hoax.

Comment: It will also trip the RCD in your fuse panel

Comment: This is just false frugality. One more wire in the cable does not increase the installation costs. Probably you have spent more time making sure, that it is a good alternative or not, so unless your time is complately free, it will probably not save you any resources. Plus, you can not be sure how well will it work, there will be uncertainty about the soil resistance, which will vary from time to time. What will happen if a lightning hits near your house? You might even loose power in the ground, which you will pay for as well. It seems like a nightmare.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How well this works will depend heavily on the bulk resistivity of the soil and the ground rods used at each end.

National Electrical Code Sec. 250-54, requires that the resistance to ground of a buildings ground rod must be 25 ohms or less.  If you attach a similar rod at the far end of your setup then the best you can guarantee is that the return path is less than 50 ohms, but how much less you can't know for sure without measuring.

If you use this setup you are effectively putting a series resistance of several 10s of ohms in series with your load.  Worst case, if the ground impedance is 50 ohms then the maximum power you can transfer to the load is (120V)^2 / 100 ohms / 2 = 72W.

- From an electrical standpoint, the main downside is not being able to deliver a lot of power.
- From a legal liability standpoint, it might not meet building codes, which by itself is good enough reason not to do it.
- From a safety standpoint, its at least possible to have proper grounding at both ends, since you need a ground rod at the far end.
- From a cost standpoint installing the extra ground rod might cost more than just buying the extra wire.

Comment: Just as a note to when this *could* work, a single cable is commonly used for HV power distribution between two places separated by sea. The difference of course is salt water as a conductor for the return path. As you say, soil isn't so good.

Comment: I think you have to devide your calculated power by two, to get only the power in the load. Right now, the 144W are the power in the load + power in the soil resistance.

Comment: The National Electric Code isn't relevant here, because that video is clearly not in the US.  However, if it were, from what I can find NEC 250.32(B) still requires a conductor to be run to connect the two grounding rods. I don't see any case where only a single conductor is allowed.

Comment: On the positive side, the chickens would quickly learn to run outside and feast on all the earthworms that pop out of the ground when the lights turn on in the chicken coop.

Comment: Are chickens immune to electric shock?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Chicken feet touch the ground only a small distance apart, so the electric gradient over that tiny portion of 90 meters is pretty small; I doubt that they would feel a tingle. Earthworms, on the other hand, don't like electricity at all: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14235/worm-catching-with-electricity

Comment: From a national electric code standpoint, ground is NOT  A CURRENT CARRYING CONDUCTOR. So there must be at least three and often 4 wires going from building to building. The three wires would be L1, neutral and ground. The four wires would be L1, L2, neutral and ground. You are never allowed to use the ground wire to carry normal load currents (per NEC in the USA).

Answer (score 12):

The main safety risk is that you are pulling up the voltage around the grounding rod.

We like to think of the Earth as a big ball of conductor that's all at zero volts.  In reality, is has a resistance.  So if you put a rod into the ground and pass a current through it, then the soil around that rod will be at a higher voltage than the rest of the ground.  It's hard to predict what the voltage gradient is, because it will depend on the nature of the rod, the current you pass and the resistivity of the soil.

This voltage gradient is a risk for humans.  But more so for four-legged livestock, which have a longer distance between their legs, and no insulating shoes.  So the worst likely risk is that you could find livestock dropping dead as they walk past the rod at either end of the connection.

Comment: Would you also be pulling up the voltage of other household appliances with grounded chassis?

Comment: @Owen Only if they are connected to the ground rod.  Appliances connected back to the supply transformer through neutral and ground wires will be fine

Answer (score 3):

It's called single-wire earth-return.  The big thing missing from your drawing is an isolation transformer between the grid and the earth-return portion of the system.  It's a viable solution when installed correctly, but the transformer part of a proper setup will likely negate the cost savings from using a single wire for a relatively short distance (100s of meters vs 10s of km) with only a chicken coop on the other end.

Comment: yeah, if you want a light in a chicken coop use portable batteries, solar, or a spotlight shining from somewhere that has a connection to the grid.

Comment: I can't don't believe earth return is actually used anywhere in 2021. I know because of my experience using electric fences that earth resistance is much too high for this near my house. At least in summer when it is dry.